# Expected number of selected vertices in a grid graph

Tags: probability, graph-theory

Consider a grid graph of $n$ vertices, where each node is connected to its $k=4$ neighbours and it wraps around at the edges. I select each vertex with a probability $p$ because I want an average of $pn$ selected vertices.

Assume that the random process I use is to select a uniform pseudo-random real number $x$ in $[0, 1]$ for each vertex and if $x < p$, I select the corresponding vertex. Let this $x$ be "the weight" of the vertex, so we can compare vertices by their weight. In case two vertices have the same weight, assume each vertex has an unique id which is used to untie, even though you may say the probability of that happening is $0$.

Now I want to respect the restriction that the minimum distance between any pair of selected vertices is $d$. So for $d=2$, there aren't any selected vertices that are neighbours (where neighbours have a distance of $1$). For that, I use the following process to remove vertices to make sure the restriction is respected: for each selected vertex $v$, I remove it if there is at least one vertex $u$ up to distance $d$ of weight smaller than $v$'s (which means $u$ was also initially selected).

What's the expected number of vertices in the end?

I'm also interested in the generalization for $k$ and $d$.

Comment: Can you say that the probability of any vertex $v$ being selected is independent of each other and it's $p/s$, where $s$ is the number of the vertices with distance smaller than $d$? (Because it's $x$ has to be $< p$ and the minimum of those vertices). So for $d=2, k=4$, you have $p/5$, so the expected number would be $np/5$?